# Rounding approach to scheduling problem in chapter 3 of The Design of Approximation Algorithms by David P. Williamson and David B. Shmoys

Tags: approximation-algorithms

Suppose we have $$ machines and $$ jobs that can start immediately, and we want to distribute jobs to minimize the longest processing time among all machines. For any $\epsilon=1/$ for some integer $$, if we are sure all jobs have processing time more than $\epsilon $ where $$ is the upper bound for the optimal longest processing time and are able to find optimal solution with processing times of all jobs rounded down to integer multiples of $\epsilon^2$, then we are able to say the job distribution we have solved is no more than $(1+\epsilon)$. However, I am not sure if this holds when $1/\epsilon$ is not an integer. I don't know if it is covered somewhere in the textbook so I would appreciate a lot if anyone can point out the part where it is explained.

For the integer case, all jobs take time more than $\epsilon$
which is an integer multiple of $\epsilon^2$, so the rounded times are at least $\epsilon$, and due to rounding, in our solution every machine takes less than $1/\epsilon$ jobs. The longest time in the rounded-down case is at most $$, and without rounding it should be less than
$$+\frac{\epsilon^2}{\epsilon}=(1+\epsilon).$$
However in the non-integer case we cannot guarantee that the rounded time is still at least $\epsilon$. The bound $$ I can get is
$$\frac{}{\epsilon }\epsilon^2>−T\Rightarrow <\frac{T}{1−}.$$
Is there a way to prove the bound 1+ or find a counter-example to this bound? Thanks for any contribution to this problem!

Comment: Alright I found a counter-example https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4798884/scheduling-problem-in-chapter-3-of-the-design-of-approximation-algorithms-by-dav/4802791#4802791